# Crystal Report asking Database Login, Only in WinXP

Tags: c#, database, crystal-reports, authentication

I need help. This is my C# code to show a report:

```
TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
Tables CrTables;

//Let's say I have a report called RptExample
RptExample objRpt = new RptExample();

//Set Static Text
txtTitle = objRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["TextTitle"] as TextObject;
txtTitle.Text = "Test";

//This is my connection info
crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SERVERNAME\\SQLEXPRESS"; 
crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DBNAME";
crConnectionInfo.UserID = "USER";
crConnectionInfo.Password = "PASS";

CrTables = objRpt.Database.Tables;

foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
{
    crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
    crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
    CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
}

//CRV is my CrystalReportViewer
CRV.LogOnInfo = crtableLogoninfos;
CRV.ReportSource = objRpt;
```

It's working OKAY in Windows 7, but when I'm trying with Windows XP, Database Login window always popped-up asking for password only (SERVERNAME, DBNAME, and USERNAME fields already filled with the right strings. Only PASSWORD went missing).

What I did wrong?

thx so much <3

**EDIT :**

I found out that this problem only occured when I'm accessing database server using public IP, and once again, only in Windows XP not in 7.

so, my connection info goes like this:

```
crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "202.70.xx.xx\\SQLEXPRESS"; 
crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DBNAME";
crConnectionInfo.UserID = "USER";
crConnectionInfo.Password = "PASS";
```

I also tried to create report using create report wizard and it also can't find my database server using public IP (202.70.xx.xx thing).

using a local database server my code works flawlessly in WinXP.

more help wud be appreciated ;)

**EDIT 2 :**

oh I forgot. I also tried to use the real server name instead of public IP of the server but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by not having sql server native client. Try installing this on your Windows XP machine:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/7/c/27c60d49-6dbe-423e-9a9e-1c873f269484/sqlncli.msi

Comment: apparently my xp machine already has that. I've tried to reinstall sqlncli but it's still not working :'(

Answer (score 0):

This could be simple SQL server or firewall configuration issue. Probably your W7 and XP computers have different IP addresses, maybe even subnets or networks?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple... This issue will happen when we use domain network as well as restricted network.

Install crystal report designer in any XP SYSTEM. Then update data source location (Refer image).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tiJ5.png)

Then build project and use... Enjoy....